# Display customer_note in order confirmation email

Tags: email-templates

I am using this code to display customer_note in order confirmation email:

```
{{var order.getCustomerNote()|escape|nl2br}}
```

But it does not show up in the email. I also checked the value of `customer_note` in `sales_order` table to make sure it's not null.
And i went to Order model:

> vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order.php

And return a test string:

```
/**
 * Return customer_note
 *
 * @return string|null
 */
public function getCustomerNote()
{
    return "i was here!";
    return $this->getData(OrderInterface::CUSTOMER_NOTE);
}
```

Surprisingly i can see my test string show up in email.

Do you have any ideas why it doesnt work?
Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this code

```
{{depend order_data.email_customer_note}}
    <table class="message-info">
        <tr>
            <td>
                {{var order_data.email_customer_note|escape|nl2br}}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
{{/depend}}
```

**`THANKS.`**